# Google Sheets SUMIF with only different sum range size than

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use the `SUMIF` function, but with a different array sizes for the range and sum ranges.

If a value appears in either columns A or B, I would like to sum the corresponding value in column C. This is the formula I tried using:

```
=SUMIF(A:B, "MYVALUE", C)
```

What I expected to happen was that it would find `MYVAULE` in A2 and B4, and then add cells C2 and C4 together.

However, it actually sums C2 and D4 together (and essentially trying to make the sum range the same size as the range, even though I ask it to use only C as the sum range).

There is a way to do this using a sum of `SUMIF` functions:

```
=SUMIF(A:A, "MYVALUE", C) + SUMIF(B:B, "MYVALUE", C)
```

This would work the way I want it to, but it wouldn't be nice if I was trying to search many columns for `MYVALUE`.

Is there a better way to do this in one formula?

Comment: It's just a string that I am testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **`=SUMIFS`** where you can refer to whole range for criteria instead of column/row like in **`=SUMIF`**

```
=SUMIFS(A1:B10;A1:B10;"=5")
```

[image]

---

or you can use **`=SUM`** with **`=FILTER`**

```
=SUM(FILTER(C:C, A:A = 3),
     FILTER(C:C, B:B = 3))
```

[image]

Comment: I apologize if I was unclear, but I am not trying to add the original range (in this case, the number 5), but I am trying to add values *corresponding* to the number 5s which are in the C column. The second longer formula I wrote in my post does what I am looking for, although it's quite verbose

Comment: @SkeletonBow I see, check my answer for update